# error: use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous (with operand types 'ObjA_' and 'char [5]')

Tags: c++, clang++

Yet, another ambiguous overloaded operator! Despite numerous questions of the kind, I have come across an another given out by `clang++-6.0` that escapes them. A typecast operator definition is making `[]` overloading to give the error. It's not making any sense to me.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct Obj_ {
   Obj_& operator [] (const char*) {
      cout << "const char* subscript." << endl;
      return *this;
   }
   Obj_& operator [] (const string&) {
      cout << "const string& subscript." << endl;
      return *this;
   }
   operator int () {
      cout << "int cast." << endl;
      return 0;
   }
};

int main () {
   Obj_ Obj;
   char Str1[5] = "test";
   string Str2 =  "test";

   Obj[Str1];
   Obj[Str2][Str1];

   return 0;
}
```

when compiled, spits out

```
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:26:7: error: 
      use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous (with operand types 'Obj_'
      and 'char [5]')
   Obj[Str1];
   ~~~^~~~~
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:7:11: note: 
      candidate function
   Obj_& operator [] (const char*) {
          ^
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:11:11: note: 
      candidate function
   Obj_& operator [] (const string&) {
          ^
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:26:7: note: 
      built-in candidate operator[](int, char *)
   Obj[Str1];
      ^
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:26:7: note: 
      built-in candidate operator[](int, const char *)
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:26:7: note: 
      built-in candidate operator[](int, volatile char *)
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:26:7: note: 
      built-in candidate operator[](int, const volatile char *)
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:27:13: error: 
      use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous (with operand types 'Obj_'
      and 'char [5]')
   Obj[Str2][Str1];
   ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:7:11: note: 
      candidate function
   Obj_& operator [] (const char*) {
          ^
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:11:11: note: 
      candidate function
   Obj_& operator [] (const string&) {
          ^
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:27:13: note: 
      built-in candidate operator[](int, char *)
   Obj[Str2][Str1];
            ^
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:27:13: note: 
      built-in candidate operator[](int, const char *)
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:27:13: note: 
      built-in candidate operator[](int, volatile char *)
/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp:27:13: note: 
      built-in candidate operator[](int, const volatile char *)
2 errors generated.
CMakeFiles/test_ambiguity.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/test_ambiguity.dir/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_ambiguity.dir/tests/test_ambiguity.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/test_ambiguity.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_ambiguity.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This compiles well by `gcc` but not by `clang`. There is no error if there is no typecast operator though it is not used!

Comment: `Str1` is an array not a pointer, so needs to be converted. There are two possible conversions, so the compiler is confused.  Live link and interesting error message: https://godbolt.org/g/ewLyCx    _"warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:"_

Comment: Fwiw, vc140 (VC++ for VS 2015, cl version 19.00.24215.1) has no problem with this.

Comment: Doesn't compile with GCC 7.2.0, for the same reasons. There are two possible conversions.

Comment: Since `Str1` is an array, `Str1[i]` is equivalent to `i[Str1]` for integers `i`, which is the reason for  the conversion to `int`. Adding implicit conversion to your classes is often a convenient way of aiming at your own foot.

Comment: A better question might be this: Why do you need an explicit `const char*` overload when you already got `const string&` for the same operator ?  If you just removed the `const char*` overload for `[]`, you would still be able to say `obj["foo"]` and it will invoke the `ObjA_& operator [] (const string&)` method.

Comment: @molbdnilo oohw! Does `C++` do that? Now it's fitting! Seems like computers are becoming difficult for other disciplines in contrary.

Comment: @selbie removing `const char*` overload also gives the error.

Comment: @NeilButterworth GCC 7.2 compiles with a sensible warning.

Comment: @RichardCritten, shouldn't *clang* also warn it instead of the error?

Comment: @neckTwi - my bad.  If you had a function `foo(const string& s)`, then you could safely pass a string literal such as `foo("xyz");` and it would work as expected.  Apparently this mechanism doesn't apply for the for `[]` operator. That might be a question for another day.

Comment: @neckTwi No, it doesn't compile. I copy and pasted your code and compiled it - the result is numerous errors, not warnings.

Comment: @NeilButterworth https://godbolt.org/g/erQuQS

Comment: @neckTwi GCC 7.2.0 (first error) `error: ambiguous overload for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'ObjA_' and 'char [5]')`

Comment: No, it's from your question. As was my original comment.